# Why is Minitube not working anymore?

Tags: minitube

When I run minitube from terminal I get:

```
No available API keys 
403 "Error downloading https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&maxResults=50&q=teste - server replied: Forbidden" 202
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know, but I recently tried minitube too and got similar errors. My guess is that Youtube changed their API to stop such applications (they can't display ads and recommendations there, maybe they also can't spy that efficient on what the user does - so they don't want it!), but that's only a guess. I am interested if you get any constructive answer.

Comment: Just installed and checked again, searching for "Serious Black" with Minitube 2.2-1 resulted in `410 "Error downloading http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?v=2&max-results=10&start-index=1&q=serious%20black - server replied: Gone" 299` for me.

Comment: Mandatory reading material: http://lwn.net/Articles/570485/ @bytecommander

Comment: I've got in version 2.5.2: NO menu, HiDDEN subscriptions. This resolves by twice of [F11]-button for the menu and tabs swithing by 'CTRL+1', 'CTRL+2', 'CTRL+3' . Other shotcuts, just in case : 'CTRL+R', 'CTRL+D', 'CTRL+Y', 'CTRL+U', 'CTRL+B', 'CTRL+SHIFT+S'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses Gnome Software Centre by default, we have found this to where the problem originates:

Here is how we solved it.

Step 1: Visit the website http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube and download the latest .deb file.

Step 2: Click on the Dash Button, Type "Ubuntu Software", Click on the Ubuntu Software Icon. When Ubuntu Software Centre opens, search for "gdebi" and using Ubuntu's Software Centre install the gdebi package installer.

Step 3: Go to your Download folder and Right click on the .deb file and select open with gdebi package installer and proceed with the installation.

Step 4: Check your version number by going to "Help" -> "About"

Step 5: Happy viewing

We think that the reason it doesn't come with a default API key and works out of the box is due to how it was originally packaged for the Ubuntu Software Centre. Additionally if you install the .deb package using the Ubuntu Software Centre (backend Gnome Software Centre) it will automatically default to the version that doesn't have an api key. This is why you need to use gdebi package installer for this to work.

Answer (score 13):

Since version 2.4 of Minitube you need to have a personal Youtube API key :

> Minitube 2.4
> A note for Linux packagers :
>
> YouTube API version 3 requires an API key. Each key has a limited
> “quota”. In order to build you need
> your own API key. - Via
> [flavio.tordini.org](http://flavio.tordini.org/on/minitube)

---

First of all you will need to get your Youtube API key. Then you have three options to chose from to make MiniTube works again properly :

1. Use install script by Noobslab
2. Modify current install and enter API key there
3. Compile MiniTube yourself

---

### Get Youtube API Key

Connect to your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and create a new project.

In your project page open **Enable Google APIs for use in your apps**, and go to :

1. **API and Auth** > **Youtube Data API** and select **Activate API**.
2. Go back in **API and Auth** > **Credentials** > **Add credentials** > **API Key** > **Browser Key**.

From what I have tried you will need a Google Account but no payment is required.

---

### Method 1 : Use Minitube.sh install script (easiest way)

[Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/minitube-version-24-released-install-in.html) created a installation script which does everything for you.

During the installation, you will be prompted to put your API key :

```
wget -O minitube.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/minitube/minitube.sh
chmod +x minitube.sh
source ./minitube.sh
```

---

### Method 2 : Use current Minitube Install

If you already have Minitube installed you can simply add your personal API Key :

```
sudo nano /etc/profile.d/minitube.sh
```

Add the following line :

```
export GOOGLE_API_KEY="your-google-api-key"
```

*Note: If you have a `qtsingleapp-minitube-xxx.lockfile` in your `/tmp` folder you will need to delete it.*

---

### Method 3 : Compile MiniTube

Once you have your personal key you can to compile Minitube.

1. Install the needed libraries to build:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential qt4-dev-tools libphonon-dev libqt4-sql-sqlite
   ```
2. Clone Minitube repository :

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube.git
   ```
3. Compile

   ```
   qmake "DEFINES += APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=YouAPIKeyHere"  
   make
   ```
4. Launch your compiled Minitube...

   ```
   build/target/minitube
   ```
5. ...or install it

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Refer to the [Minitube repository](https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube) for more information on how to build Minitube with a personal API Key.

Comment: Does getting that key require signing up to anything and payment?

Comment: When I try to compile, I get QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced. How do I set QMAKESPEC ?

Comment: @adonis Good point, I have edited my answer ;)

Comment: Second option also not working here. Could it be because I used the wrong method to pick API key? I got a browser credential for youtube (your sequence of menus is not what I see on my browser so I had to create a project and choose youtube API and then browser credential... )

Comment: What Minitube version are you using ? You can also try Method 3 now :p 
See [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/minitube-version-24-released-install-in.html) instructions with screenshots to make sure you got the right API Key.

Comment: I just tried method3 and I got an error. Does the download scritp include a makefile?

Comment: Yes it use a makefile, have you take a look to the [Readme](https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube#build-instructions) of Minitube repo ?  "Beware of the Qt3 or Qt5 version of qmake! If things go wrong try running qmake-qt4 instead." maybe your problem come from here ?

Comment: I wonder whether is good idea to place the `export GOOGLE_API_KEY="your-google-api-key"` into ~/.bashrc. Thus the local user will have his own key.