# .deb Installed Minitube 3.0 does not launch on ubuntu 16.04 and on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04, software-installation, qt

I updated the `minitube` into version 3.0 via a deb package provided from the website (https://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) but when I try to launch it it simply does not open. Thus I tried via terminal and I get the following errors:

```
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5X11Extras.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by minitube)
```

I tried as seen from github repository to install the following libraries:

```
sudo apt install build-essential qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qt5-qmake qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5x11extras5-dev libmpv-dev
```

Still failed to launch. I purged the `minitube`:

```
sudo apt-get purge minitube
```

And I reinstalled it:

```
sudo dpkg -i minitube.deb
```

Still no light in my path.

I also created an ubuntu 18.04 VM and tried to install in it:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5qml5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libmpv1
# Install the browser downloaded deb
sudo dkpg -i minitube.deb
```

Still fails to launch with the error:

```
minitube: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by minitube)
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

## Edit 1

In the end managed to compile the v2.9 in Ubuntu 18.04 Vm but failed to play a video even if the video list is loaded correctly.

## Edit 2

On ubuntu 16.04LTS I have installed the `phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer` via `apt` still fails to launch the .deb installed version.

Comment: Installation of packages mentioned [on github page](https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube) are needed to compile the package, they should not change anything with binary version. You may try to compile it following https://askubuntu.com/a/672505/66509 .

Comment: So in other words I should build it by myrself right?

Comment: You may try, but I am not sure that it would work as it will not change the Qt version of the system. Faster method - is to try Ubuntu 18.10 on VM (it has [minitube 2.9-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=minitube)).

Comment: Well repo bases ones do work but on Ubuntu18.04vm the minitube 2.5.x has been installed.

Comment: the latest  (3.0/2.9) requires qt 5.6 at a min but has to be built on whatever your on. His packages may only work on 18.10. To see I built the 3.0 git on both 18.04 and 19.04, works ok. If you build you need to use a Google API Key. See the readme in the source.  As getting key is a pita just use debian's, i.e  `qmake DEFINES+=APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=AIzaSyC9EDpL8xpx_EcAbTbn66wbMwMzqzSI3MM`

Comment: As far as 16.04, both 2.9 and 3.0 could work. 3.0 uses libmpv, you'd need at least 0.28, maybe 0.29. mintube 2.9 is phonon based so that may prove easier, needs `phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer` to run, `libphonon4qt5-dev` to build (in addition..

Comment: But `phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer` is installed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the slight older minitube 2.9 version via flatpak tested in ubuntu 16.04LTS and Ubuntu 18.04LTS https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.tordini.flavio.Minitube

In order to install flatpak consult the following blog post:
https://omgfoss.com/install-flatpak-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver/

Note:
If on the ubuntu 18.04LTS the minitube does not show in the Activities then logout and login again.

Whilst on ubuntu 18.04LTS I did manage to build manually the `libmpv` as seen in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1128842/540746). So buidling it is one way to bypass the problem for Ubuntu 18.04LTS, as seen in the comment. If you can read Greek, then you can have a look in my [blog](https://wp.me/pRFAL-hu) for the build instructions.

Officialy the developer does not want to support older version of ubuntu as seen in this github [post](https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube/issues/124#issuecomment-476519121) due to `libmpv` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

As of 23 Apr 2019 Minitube 2.9 stopped working on Linux Mint 18.2. I think youtube changed their addressing structures so Minitube 2.9 can no longer find the address. The subscription updates continue and the titles are still there, but nothing will play. The player will skip to the next vid, and then the next, etc. I installed Linux Mint 19.1 and got VLC and mPlayer working with Nouveau since the nVidia 304 driver is no longer available. But minitube 3.0 won't work because it is expecting qt5 version 5.11 and this distribution only has qt5 version 5.9.5. So I am stuck without minitube until the Mint update gives me a later qt5 version.

update: 25 Apr 2019 - minitube 2.9 on Mint 18.2 has started working again. I can only guess that youtube has changed back something that they messed with in the first place. I will have to wait for Mint 19.1 to update their repositories to qt5 ver. 5.11 for the minitube 3.0 to start working. Until that time I will stay with using Mint 18.2 and the 2.9 version of minitube.

Answer (score 1):

minitube 3.1 en ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic
```

```
sudo apt -y install qt512-meta-minimal
```

```
source /opt/qt512/bin/qt512-env.sh && minitube
```