# Failed building minitube with compiled libmpv v0.29.0

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, compiling, make

According to the author of minitube the latest version of minitube requires libmpv => 0.29.0 that is not delivered by repositories or via [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests). The one that ubuntu 18.04LTS deliver is the libmpv 0.27.0 one.

So I thought:

> If I build the libmpv my myself I could be able to build the latest version of minitube!!!!

So I installed the required for building the minitube except `libmpv-dev`:

```
sudo apt install build-essential qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qt5-qmake qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

And the requirements for libmpv:

```
sudo apt-get install autoreconf lilfreetype-dev libfribidi-dev libfontconfig-dev yasm
```

And I cloned the `mpv-build` github [repo](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build). Afterwards I geve the following sequence of commands

```
cd mpv-build
echo --enable-libmpv-shared > mpv_options
./use-mpv-custom v0.29.0
./update
./rebuild -j4
sudo ./install
```

Afterwards I tried to build the minitube after cloning the minitube github [repo](https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube) and giving the following sequence of commands:

```
cd mintube
qmake "DEFINES += APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY=YourAPIKeyHere"
make
```

But I get the following error:

```
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `MpvWidget::~MpvWidget()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_free'
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `non-virtual thunk to MpvWidget::~MpvWidget()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_free'
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `MpvWidget::initializeGL()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x399): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_create'
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x3b9): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_set_update_callback'
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `MpvWidget::paintGL()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_render'
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `MpvWidget::onFrameSwapped()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_report_swap'
build/obj/mpvwidget.o: In function `MpvWidget::maybeUpdate()':
mpvwidget.cpp:(.text+0x807): undefined reference to `mpv_render_context_report_swap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:630: recipe for target 'build/target/minitube' failed
```

Do you know how to successfully build it in ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to remove any libmpv package?
Run:

```
sudo apt-get purge libmpv-dev libmpv && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Afterwards install the required packages for sound:

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev libx246-dev libfbdc-aac-dev
```

Afterwards recompile with these steps:

```
cd mpv-build
echo --enable-libmpv-shared > mpv_options
# Enable sound on minitube videos
echo --enable-libx264 >> ffmpeg_options
echo --enable-libmp3lame >> ffmpeg_options
echo --enable-libfdk-aac >> ffmpeg_options
./use-mpv-custom v0.29.0
./update
./rebuild -j4
sudo ./install
```

Also let the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point into `/usr/local/lib` via:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And for more permanent results use either one of these commands:

- For your local user only:

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

- For all users/global use:

```
echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 2):

libmpv => 0.29.0 (0.29.1~bionic2) that is delivered by via [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-media).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/bionic-media
```

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped installing Stremio on a Lubuntu 18.04 32 bits.