# Install Qt > 5.10 on ubuntu 18.04 in order to build the minitube 3.2

Tags: software-installation, compiling, qt, minitube

For building the minitube ( https://github.com/flaviotordini/minitube ) I need to have a version later than the one offered by the repositories. The reason I am asking is because the developer supports Later Ubuntu versions than the LTS one (18.04)

So I need to build it by myself. Also, I have installed previous versions of minitube by manually compiling it.

Based upon this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153068/540746) I used the `ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic`
  but misses the `qttools512-dev-tools` package hence the build fails on:

```
/opt/qt512/bin/lrelease locale/ar.ts -qm build/target/locale/ar.qm
make: /opt/qt512/bin/lrelease: Command not found
Makefile:904: recipe for target 'build/target/locale/ar.qm' failed
make: *** [build/target/locale/ar.qm] Error 127
```

SO how I can install a later version of qt in order to build the `minitube`. Also keep in mind that the solution should not require the whole QTCreator because I find it kinda bloated in norder to use it just for a built.

Comment: 18.04 is the LTS one and fits my needs.

Comment: Generally you shouldnt need or use ppa's for installing Qt. Just grab the installer from the Qt website, and that handles versions.